# how to distinguish between "of which" and "which"?

Tags: clauses

> A. One can produce fluent speech **of which** *it* is difficult to make sound.
>
> B. One can produce fluent speech  **which** is difficult to make sound.

I wonder if there is any difference in meaning  between these. I am wondering what the word "it" refers to.

I would like to say:

> Fluent speech is difficult to comprehend by listening to it.

. . . .

> “The type of language disorder that results in difficulties in auditory comprehension is sometimes called "sensory aphasia," but is more commonly known as Wernicke's aphasia. Someone suffering from this disorder can actually produce very **fluent speech which is, however, often difficult to make sense of.** Very general terms are used, even in response to specific requests for information, as in this sample: I can't talk all of the things I do, and part of the part I can go alright, but I can't tell from the other people.”

Excerpt From: George Yule. “The Study Of Language.” iBooks.

Comment: The verb is "produce", not "product".

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "make sound".

The sentence (A) is missing the subject in the subclause.  Needs to be
> ... *of which* **it** *is difficult ...*

The sentence (B) is grammatically OK, but the meaning is that the fluent speech presents difficulties for anyone who tries to do something that would improve it (see the meaning of 'sound' as an adjective).

Perhaps you would like to say that fluent speech is difficult to comprehend by listening to it?  Or do you mean that fluent speech can be difficult to reproduce?

Comment: Perhaps you meant "difficult to _make out_ the sound"—that is, difficult for the hearer to parse the fluid sounds into recognizable words.

Comment: fluent speech <==> make sound

This 2 don't seem correlated. Are you sure the sentence is

One can produce fluent speech of which it is difficult to make sound.

and not

One can produce fluent speech of which it is difficult to make sense.

Comment: Overformatting stuff doesn't do anything other than hurting the readers' eyes.

Comment: nima, it seems to me both your example sentences are "gibberish". The reason for that, as @Victor has repeatedly pointed out, is because you've changed George Yule's perfectly valid ***sense*** to ***sound*** (which is effectively "nonsense" here). The fact that you've placed a bounty prevents me from closevoting at the moment, but I will do so when the bounty expires, if you haven't amended the question by then to clarify exactly what you're asking about.

Comment: @FumbleFingers that's not the only reason. The addition of "of" in "of which" makes no sense as well in the first example.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take the example you gave from George Yule and rewrite it without ending it with a preposition.

> ... can actually produce very fluent speech of which to make sense is, however, often difficult.

Now, let's parse it.  The entire end of the sentence

> ***of which to make sense is, however, often difficult.***

is an adjectival phrase that defines "*speech*".  We can drop some emphasizing words from it getting

> ***of which to make sense is difficult.***

Here "*is difficult*" is the adverbial phrase for the verb "*make*" (and "*sense*" is its direct object).

Is it now a bit simpler to understand?

After dropping some other words from the clause with which we started, we have

> ... can produce speech of which to make sense is difficult.

The same clause can be rewritten to bring the "*is difficult*" forward:

> ... can produce speech of which *it* is difficult to make sense.

So, in conclusion, you can write with the preposition in the front of the clause that starts with "which", or you can end the clause with the preposition (although it is considered more casual to do so):

> *Here is evidence **on which** we can rely.*
>   *Here is evidence **which** we can rely **on**.*

I think in your question you missed the fact that (1) the author used the word "sense" and not "sound" and (2) the sentence ended with the preposition.  Whether to use the preposition, and which preposition to use, is governed by the verb, in your George Yule's quote it's "*make* (sense)" that requires "*of*", in my last example, it's "*rely*" which requires "*on*".

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get your first example from? The one that says "of which it is"? I ask because at least in this context, it is a little off. [Victor](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/65105/20827) has given a good technical analysis, I'd like to try to explain with some simpler language and examples.

When you add the preceding "of", you're referring to the group that the selected "which" belongs to, because "which" is a selective term referring to one of many options. The "it" immediately following "which" is a reference back to the previously named selection. Depending on the context, it could be omitted or replaced with the explicit naming of the entity being singled out from the group. Some examples:

> I have a basket of mixed fruit, the best tasting of which are the
> oranges.
>
> There are many poisonous plants in my region, including Hogweed, of
> which it is the most dangerous.

In both cases, "of" is explicitly referring to the named group that the following selected item belongs to, fruit and poisonous plants respectively. In my second example, "it" is simply a reference back to the item selected from the group, which I've also previously named. Therefore I need not name it again, the item in question of course being Hogweed. In fact referring to it again by name wouldn't be fluid or "natural", but would still be correct:

> There are many poisonous plants in my region, including Hogweed, of
> which Hogweed is the most dangerous.

Rewritten examples to further illustrate these word functions:

> I have a basket of mixed fruit. The best tasting fruit in the basket
> are the oranges.
>
> There are many poisonous plants in my region, including Hogweed. The
> most dangerous of them all is Hogweed.

By now you can probably see why your first example is a little off. There is nothing preceding the example to provide a context where "of" could refer to something. Since we have a broken context at "of", the "it" which is another reference predicated on a clear definition in "of" falls apart too.

In the context, we're not discussing types of speech, plus fluent speech isn't really a distinct type of speech separate from many other forms of speech. Rather, fluent speech is simply a more refined form of speech. There is no basket of different types of speech to choose from, there are no two forms of speech where one is an apple and the other an orange. Just ripe and partially ripe apples. :)

However, all that said, I believe what you were truly meaning to say by adding "it" in the first example is simply:

> Joe speaks very fluently. It is difficult to understand.

For the final portion of your question. If you want to express that fluent speech can be difficult to understand when hearing it, you said it yourself just fine.

> Fluent speech can be difficult to comprehend when hearing it.
>
> It can be difficult to understand speech when spoken fluently.
>
> I have a hard time understanding some things that are said by fluent
> speakers.